# How can I move circles in groups in pygame at the same time?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I've been working on this project for a long time, and I have finally finished the second last step to complete this project. My project draws a spirograph using pygame. Then it moves all of the circles away from its original place and stops at the borders of the window. There is a catch, though. The catch is that I have to move all of the circles
in one group at the same time, based on their color. So basically, since there are 5 circles per color, I want to move all of the 5 circles of a color at once. Then, when the first group of circles is done moving, continue on to the next color. Afterwards, the circles of the next color start moving etc. The red circles start, then the blue ones and then the green ones.

So far, I have only managed to move all of the circles at once, not the each five circles per color. Is there any way to do this?

This is my current code:

```
import time
import pygame
import math
import sys

# setting colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 127, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
PURPLE = (160, 32, 240)
# setting what order the colors go in
listCircleColor = (RED, BLUE, GREEN, ORANGE, YELLOW, PURPLE, WHITE)
# how many circles per color
intGroup = 5
# the space between each circle
turnangle = 360 / 35
# width of screen
width = 600
# height of screen
height = 600
# radius of circles
radius = 100
# making the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
# if the code is running, then continue
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

##.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (0, 0), radius, width=2)
alpha = turnangle
circles = []
# draw
alpha = turnangle
for i in range(intGroup):
    for cl in listCircleColor:
        if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
            x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
            y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
            # second quarter of circles
        if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha))
            y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
            # third quarter of circles
        if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha - 180))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha - 180))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
            # last quarter of circles
        if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
            x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)

        circles.append(([x, y], cl, alpha))
        alpha = alpha + turnangle
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(10)
        #circle = [pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha)), 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))), radius, width=2)]
        #circles = {'circles': circle.get_rect()}

# move"
trangleedge = radius
movetimes = 1
time.sleep(2)



# exit only when user clicks on exit button
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    while movetimes <= 100:
        trangleedge = trangleedge + 1
        for circle in circles:
            #x = circle[0][0]
            #y = circle[0][1]
            alpha = circle[2]
            cl = circle[1]

            if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
                x = 300 + trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
                y = 300 + trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                # second quarter of circles
            if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
                x = 300 - trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha))
                y = 300 + trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                # third quarter of circles
            if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
                x = 300 - trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(alpha - 180))
                y = 300 - trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(alpha - 180))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                # last quarter of circles
            if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
                x = 300 + trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha))
                y = 300 - trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)

            circle[0][0] = x
            circle[0][1] = y
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            for center, color, alpha in circles:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, center, radius, 2)

            pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        movetimes += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to loop trough the different colors and repeat the animation for each of them. Here's my code (only the second loop, the rest remains the same.):

```py
# exit only when user clicks on exit button
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    #prevent the animation from continuing forever
    if moveoutside:
        #loop trough different colors
        for circlecolor in listCircleColor:
            #reset loop variables to prevent weird things
            trangleedge=radius
            movetimes=1
            while movetimes <= 100:
                
                trangleedge = trangleedge + 1
                              #only redraw circles with a certain color
                for circle in [x for x in circles if x[1]==circlecolor]:
                    #x = circle[0][0]
                    #y = circle[0][1]
                    alpha = circle[2]
                    cl = circle[1]

                    if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
                        x = 300 + trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
                        y = 300 + trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
                        #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                        # second quarter of circles
                    if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
                        x = 300 - trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha))
                        y = 300 + trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))
                        #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                        # third quarter of circles
                    if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
                        x = 300 - trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(alpha - 180))
                        y = 300 - trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(alpha - 180))
                        #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                        # last quarter of circles
                    if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
                        x = 300 + trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha))
                        y = 300 - trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))
                        #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)

                    circle[0][0] = x
                    circle[0][1] = y
                    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
                    for center, color, alpha in circles:
                        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, center, radius, 2)

                    pygame.display.flip()
                clock.tick(60)
                movetimes += 1
        #prevent the animation from continuing forever
        moveoutside=False
```